# WIFI suddenly stops connecting?

Tags: wireless, networking

I'm dual-booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.10, and one day Ubuntu stopped being able to connect to wireless. It still sees the network, it just can't connect to it. I don't have a wired connection available, so I can't run aptitude update or upgrade.

I don't know a lot about connectivity troubleshooting, but when I did iwconfig, it said "No network connections" under Wireless. I'm on Windows now to type this, so I don't have the exact wording.

Windows 8 has the weird UEFI thing, otherwise I would do my old trick of reinstalling Ubuntu all over again. But that's probably not the best thing to do.

Any help?

EDIT:

```
 laura@bbydhyonchord:~$ dmesg | tail -n 50
 [   56.948484] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: FH TRBs(3) = 0x80300002
 [   56.948497] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: FH TRBs(4) = 0x00000000
 [   56.948511] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: FH TRBs(5) = 0x00000000
 [   56.948524] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: FH TRBs(6) = 0x00000000
 [   56.948538] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: FH TRBs(7) = 0x00709041
 [   56.948592] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 0 is active and mapped to fifo 3 ra_tid 0x0000 [2,3]
 [   56.948648] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 1 is active and mapped to fifo 2 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.948703] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 2 is active and mapped to fifo 1 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,30]
 [   56.948758] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 3 is active and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.948814] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 4 is active and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.948869] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 5 is active and mapped to fifo 4 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.948925] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 6 is active and mapped to fifo 2 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.948980] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 7 is active and mapped to fifo 5 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.949035] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 8 is active and mapped to fifo 4 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.949090] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 9 is active and mapped to fifo 7 ra_tid 0x0000 [66,66]
 [   56.949146] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 10 is active and mapped to fifo 5 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.949201] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 11 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.949256] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 12 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.949312] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 13 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.949367] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 14 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.949422] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 15 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.949478] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 16 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.949533] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 17 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.949588] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 18 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.949644] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 19 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
 [   56.975498] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
 [   56.977687] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
 [   56.977689] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
 [   56.977691] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
 [   56.977692] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
 [   56.977693] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
 [   56.977694] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
 [   56.977695] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
 [   57.168191] wlan0: authenticate with 00:19:77:44:a6:94
 [   57.173685] wlan0: send auth to 00:19:77:44:a6:94 (try 1/3)
 [   57.175275] wlan0: authenticated
 [   57.175350] wlan0: waiting for beacon from 00:19:77:44:a6:94
 [   57.212574] wlan0: associate with 00:19:77:44:a6:94 (try 1/3)
 [   57.214526] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:19:77:44:a6:94 (capab=0x421 status=0 aid=1)
 [   57.233990] wlan0: associated
 [   57.234033] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
 [   57.235870] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
 [   57.235872] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
 [   57.235874] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
 [   57.235875] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
 [   57.235875] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
 [   57.235876] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
 [   57.235877] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
 [   57.235878] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
 [   57.235878] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)


 laura@bbydhyonchord:~$ nmcli -p d
 ===========================================
              Status of devices
 ===========================================
 DEVICE     TYPE              STATE        
 -------------------------------------------
 eth0       802-3-ethernet    unavailable  
 wlan0      802-11-wireless   connecting (getting IP configuration)



 laura@bbydhyonchord:~$ iwconfig
 eth0      no wireless extensions.

 lo        no wireless extensions.

 wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"W-M_Wireless"  
           Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:19:77:44:A6:94   
           Bit Rate=11 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
           Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
           Power Management:off
           Link Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
           Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: When you try to connect use the terminal and type `dmesg | tail -n 50` and also add the output of `nmcli -p d` and `iwconfig`.